# Derivation of effective mass equation in carbon nanotubes

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, graphene, nanoscience, tight-binding

I am trying to reproduce the calculations in the paper [here](http://journals.jps.jp/doi/abs/10.1143/JPSJ.67.1704) by Ando and Nakanishi and am already stuck on equation 1. It is stated that in the vicinity of $\epsilon=0$ the amplitude of the wavefunction at $\mathbf{R}_A$ and $\mathbf{R}_B$ is written as

$$ \psi(\mathbf{R}_A) = \exp(i \mathbf{K}\cdot\mathbf{R}_A)F_A^K(\mathbf{R}_A) + \exp(i \eta)\exp(i \mathbf{K'}\cdot\mathbf{R}_A)F_A^{K'}(\mathbf{R}_A) $$
$$ \psi(\mathbf{R}_B) = -\omega \exp(i \eta)\exp(i \mathbf{K}\cdot\mathbf{R}_B)F_B^K(\mathbf{R}_B) + \exp(i \mathbf{K'}\cdot\mathbf{R}_B)F_B^{K'}(\mathbf{R}_B) $$

where $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/3)$, $\eta$ is the chiral angle, the $F$'s are envelope functions, and $\mathbf{K}^{(')}$ are the inequivalent degeneracy points in the Brillouin zone. I do not understand how to derive these equations. Could anybody point me in the right direction, or provide relevant resources?

Comment: Each site-specific $\psi$ is a superposition of typical Bloch wave functions of the form $e^{i{\bf k}\cdot{\bf r}}u({\bf r})$, one from each of the two bands contributing to the site states.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's the phase factors that are mostly confusing me, but I think maybe they are purely a choice made with hindsight to simplify the final result?

Comment: Yes, I suspect the phase factors are selected to match the geometry, both for the 2D sheet and the rolled CNTs, given the reference to the chiral vector in defining $\eta$.